# rare InflateException on ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-inflate

1. `Activity` with `ViewPager`
2. each page is `Fragment`, which is inflating custom layout-template
3. content (JSON) is downloading (using `Loader`) for each `Fragment` and after download I'm fulfilling previously inflated layout.
4. inside layout I have container to which I'm adding manually "lines" (after downloading I know how much), layout here:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <com.custom.mobile.widgets.ForegroundLinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="8dp"
       android:paddingRight="8dp"
       app:foregroundCompat="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/poll_option_single_row_option_percent"
               android:layout_width="56dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
               android:textSize="16sp"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:visibility="invisible"/>
           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/poll_option_single_row_option_radio"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:gravity="center"/>
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/poll_option_single_row_option_text"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poll_option_single_row_option_percent"
               android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
               android:paddingLeft="8dp"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
               android:textSize="16sp" />
       </RelativeLayout>
       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/poll_option_single_row_option_progress"
           style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:max="100"
           android:visibility="invisible"/>
   </com.custom.mobile.widgets.ForegroundLinearLayout>
   ```

[source of ForegroundLinearLayout might be found here](https://github.com/cesards/ForegroundViews/blob/master/foregroundviews/src/main/java/com/cesards/android/foregroundviews/ForegroundLinearLayout.java), probably not related with problem, which is veeery rare and independently of OS version or manufacturer:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout$PollHolder.(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout.printPoll(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout.init(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.preparePoll(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.prepareArticleView(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.displayArticle(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.onLoadFinished(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.integration.asyncloader.AsyncLoader.deliverResult(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$400(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout$PollHolder.(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout.printPoll(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout.init(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.preparePoll(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.prepareArticleView(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.displayArticle(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.onLoadFinished(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.integration.asyncloader.AsyncLoader.deliverResult(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$400(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 155148 byte allocation with 129688 free bytes and 126KB until OOM
   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:827)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:646)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1019)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3778)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3651)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1865)
   at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:319)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1155)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1068)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3767)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3651)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
   at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:357)
   at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:313)
   at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:309)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout$PollHolder.(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout.printPoll(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.widgets.PollLayout.init(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.preparePoll(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.prepareArticleView(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.displayArticle(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.activity.fragment.ArticleFragment.onLoadFinished(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Unknown Source)
   at com.custom.mobile.integration.asyncloader.AsyncLoader.deliverResult(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$400(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

which is caused by line:

```
li.inflate(R.layout.option_single_row_layout, root, false);
```

I can't figure out how to recreate bug conditions... XML line number point on `<ProgressBar`. I've done some changes in this layout and line number changed after release, still pointing on `<ProgressBar`... help, please... :/

Comment: "Caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 155148 byte allocation with 129688 free bytes and 126KB until OOM" what are you showing? pics?

Comment: I'm setting only text for two `TextViews`... `ProgressBar` have custom drawables for 4.x (small for sure), but problem occurs also in 5+

Answer (score 0):

Check out one of your xml's..may be you are giving wrong path for your custom layout in your xml

Comment: If that were the case it would always fail

Comment: which XML? `Exception` is pointing stright on this one line with `ProgressBar`. also like Tim wrote: wrong path will fail always. but here it's rare, very rare, and I can't reproduce it for any debug... all I have are logs from users

Comment: I suggest this because of this line: "Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class <unknown>"